# iPhone app that allows disabling upcoming alarms

Tags: iphone, alarm

In Android, it's possible to dismiss an upcoming alarm before it goes off (for example, because you woke up before your alarm). Is there an iPhone alarm app that provides this functionality?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you’ve tried, say with Siri, so we can get a better idea of exactly what you want?

Comment: Ah, sorry - didn’t see this was asked 3 years ago! I tried both “cancel next alarm” and “dismiss next alarm”. Siri recognized which alarm, but did just turn it off completely. Still apparently need another app...

Comment: I still don't see an answer for this?  My wife's android makes this very easy...